# how to set invisible a view in titanium

Tags: android, titanium, opacity

I am working at an `Android` app in `Titanium`. I must set some view as invisible. I tried this :

```
myView.setOpacity(0)
```

but instead to have an invisible view I get the strongest color of view. Any idea how to solve this?

EDIT: I need to detect when the invisible view is touched (`addEventListener` to work).

Comment: what do you have in that view ?

Comment: I have as background of the screen an image with a man. I detect with this view the location of his head (for example) and I want that when the view is touched to play a video about that location (some exercises for head)

Comment: for Iphone in Titanium setOpacity(0.11) works fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found this solution : if I don't set any color to my view, than the view is created and is invisible (like I want it to be). And addEventListner is working.
 This works for me.